# Why Linq to Sql makes SELECT * instead of SELECT COUNT(*) when I need only Count?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

We use Entity Framework and this leads to big performance problems whenever we use Count() on child collections of database entities.
As workaround I've used joins of root collections of data context. Then the resulting sql query uses the desired COUNT(*). But this solution is really ugly.

The slow query is:

```
var booked = erf.Sessions.All(s => s.Exams.All(e => e.Candidates.Count() >= e.CandidatesExpected))
```

Comment: could you post your entity framework query?

Comment: Looks like you don't have already loaded entities (otherwise Count() would not be an issue), so the problem is how to get Count() without loading all entities. The answer is using explicit loading with `Query`, e.g: `var count = context.Entry(someEntity).Collection("someNavigationProperty").Query().Count();`

Comment: @Hopeless You are correct. The problem is that the collections are nested. I've added the query to the question. What to do in such a case?

Comment: have you tried viewing the generated SQL query? it does not look like `Candidates` will be loaded. When you write `e.Candidates.Count()`, EF is  smart enough to not load all Candidates to just count the items. I've tested this, it's not the same as your query but it has the same scenario (nested query): `var first = context.students.Where(e => e.Courses.Count() > 0).First(); context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; var courses = first.Courses;`. The `courses` has Count of ***0***. That means it has not been loaded by `e.Courses.Count()`. U should consider other aspects to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If by "child collections" you mean navigation properties of type `ICollection<T>` defined in your entities, then it's Linq-to-Entities (not Linq-to-Sql, as you specified). Thus your `Count()` method is just an extension method defined in `Enumerable` class, which is executed on entities already materialized into memory. To get results you are expecting, you need to use Count() on DbSet queries.